# What's the best way to restore the arrows to my scroll bars?

Tags: gtk3

I'm running Debian Jessie.

```
$ gnome-session --version  
gnome-session 3.14.0  

$ dpkg -s libgtk-3-0 | grep '^Version'  
Version: 3.14.5-1
```

I can restore the scroll bar arrows by doing:

Applications->System Tools->Tweak Tool
In Appearance, change GTK+ to HighContrast vs. Adwaita (default)

But where do these changes get saved ?

Comment: Trying to get the arrows back on my scroll bars. GTK startup/config is confusing...

Comment: I can acually use Applications->System Tools->Tweak Tool. Change GTK+ to HighContrast vs. Adwaita (default). But where does this change get saved ? I looked at file: /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk.css but it only contains: /* Adwaita is the default theme of GTK+ 3, this file is not used */

Comment: That's better. The changes get saved in a binary file (`dconf` user database). I'm not sure why you ask that because, as I said, this is a theme thing (the theme draws the arrows... or not, the `dconf` db only stores the name of the theme, nothing else). So, you either use a theme that uses scrollbar arrows/buttons or try to modify Adwaita (there are several suggestion floating around but none of them works with newer versions of Adwaita).

Answer (score 10):

Quick fix, wfm:

```
cat <<HERE >~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
.scrollbar {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;
  }
HERE
```

I came up with that after reading this more involved solution involving editing the system theme files:
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/200938/question-about-gtkscrollbar-class-in-custom-themes

Comment: Great, this also works with other themes, e.g. DeLorean.

Comment: For GTK+ 3.20+, you need to omit the leading dot, i. e. `scrollbar {/* ... */}`.

Comment: @Bass alternatively, you could handle both: `.scrollbar, scrollbar {`